# Why does replacing text with textarea break my form?

Tags: python, html, forms, textarea

I have a form on an HTML page with an `input type="text"` that I'm replacing with a `textarea`. Now the form no longer works. When I try to submit it, I get an error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'updated_details' referenced before assignment" referring to my python code (I didn't change the python at all).

**Old line in HTML**

```
<input type="text"  name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Write stuff here." style="height:150px"> </input>
```

**New Line in HTML**

```
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Write stuff here"  </input>
</textarea>
```

**Full HTML form**

```
<form action = "/insert_vote" method = "post" onsubmit="">
    <div id="vote-form" action = "/insert_vote" method = "post" onsubmit="">
        <div class="smalltext">
            {% for dict_item in vote_choices %}
                <input type="radio" name="options" padding="10px" margin="10px" id="{{ dict_item['id'] }}"
                value="{{ dict_item['id'] }}"> {{ dict_item['choice'] }} </input><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="mediumlefttext">
            Why did you make that choice?
        </div>
<!--        <input type="text"  name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Write stuff here." style="height:150px">  </input> <br>-->

<textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Write stuff here"  </input>
</textarea>

<!--<button onclick="javascript:login();" size="large" type="submit" value="Submit" scope="public_profile,email" returnscopes="true" onlogin="checkLoginState();">Submit</button>-->
        <input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" style="display:none;">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Python**

```
@app.route('/insert_vote', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def insert_vote():
    posted = 1
    global article, user_id
    print ("insert_vote", "this should be the facebook user id", user_id)
    if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'GET':
        if not request.form['options'] or request.form['comments']:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
        else:
            rate = 0 # rate of votes protection against no votes
            vote_choice_id = int(request.form['options'])
            comments       = request.form['comments']
            # user_id = request.form['user_id']
            #user_id = 1
            av_obj = ArticleVote(user_id, article.id, vote_choice_id, comments)
            db.session.add(av_obj)
            try: 
                db.session.commit()
            except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
               flash('User has already voted on this article.')
               posted = 0

            if posted == 1:
                flash('Record was successfully added')
            else:
                db.session.rollback()

            a_obj = article # this is the current global article
            avs_obj = retrieve_article_vote_summary(a_obj.id)  # vote_summary is a list of [tuples('True', numOfTrue), etc]
            total_votes = avs_obj.getTotalVotes()
            vote_choice_list = VoteChoice.getVoteChoiceList()
            vote_choices = []
            for item in vote_choice_list:  # looping over VoteChoice objects
                num = avs_obj.getVoteCount(item.choice)
                if total_votes > 0:
                    rate = num / total_votes
                vote_choices.append([item.choice, item.color, num, rate*100, total_votes])

            details = avs_obj.getVoteDetails()  # 10/02 - retrieve array of tuples [(user, VoteChoice, Comments)]
            details_count = 0
            for detail in details:
                details_count += 1
        return redirect('/results/' + str(article.id))
```

...

```
@app.route('/results/<int:id>')
def results(id):
    rate = 0  # either 0 or num/total
    article_list_of_one = Article.query.filter_by(id=id)
    a_obj = article_list_of_one[0]

    avs_obj = retrieve_article_vote_summary(a_obj.id) # vote_summary is a list of [tuples('True', numOfTrue), etc]
    total_votes = avs_obj.getTotalVotes()
    vote_choices = []
    vote_choice_list = VoteChoice.getVoteChoiceList()
    for item in vote_choice_list: # looping over VoteChoice objects
        num = avs_obj.getVoteCount(item.choice)
        if total_votes > 0:        # protecting against no votes
            rate = num/total_votes 
        vote_choices.append([item.choice, item.color, num, rate*100, total_votes])

    details = avs_obj.getVoteDetails() # 10/02 - retrieve array of tuples [(user, VoteChoice, Comments)]
    print("Inside results(" + str(id) + "):")
    details_count = 0
    for detail in details:
        updated_details = [(user, VoteChoice, Comments, User.query.filter_by(name=user).first().fb_pic)
                           for (user, VoteChoice, Comments) in details]
        #print("    " + str(details_count) + ": " + details[0] + " " + details[1] + " " + details[2])
        # details_count += 1

    return render_template('results.html', title=a_obj.title, id=id,
                           image_url=a_obj.image_url, url=a_obj.url,
                           vote_choices=vote_choices, home_data=Article.query.all(),
                           vote_details=updated_details)
```

Comment: start with removing </input> from inside the <textarea>-tag

Answer (score 0):

remove the closing input tag

```html
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Write stuff here"  </input>
</textarea>
```

```html
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Write stuff here">
</textarea>
```

and on the python code instantiate the `details_count` out side of the `for` loop, because if the length of `details` is 0 then `details_count` would be left unassigned

Comment: seems like details has length of 0 try checking that

Comment: details is made up of a number of things being sent in the form, all of which worked until I changed "text" to "textarea"

Answer (score 0):

It is because avs_obj.getVoteDetails() is returning empty list, and your flow isn't passing through for detail in details: function.

Try removing `laceholder="Write stuff here"  </input>` stray input tag and also checking avs_obj.getVoteDetails() logic.

Comment: Tried removing the /input and placeholder bit, that didn't work. I don't see anything wrong with avs_obj.getVoteDetails()  logic --- it was working fine when I was using "text" rather than "textarea". I'll add the python that relates specifically to the form to the question